# map two array of object by common value js

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

```
const object1: [{
  "code": "lap-143240121",
  "index": 0
}, {
  "code": "lap-15040293",
  "index": 1
}, {
  "code": "lp-1504444",
  "index": 2
}, {
  "code": "lp-150440987",
  "index": 3
}]

const object2: [{
  "code": "lap-143240121",
  "name": "name1"
}, {
  "code": "lap-15040293",
  "name": "name2"
}, {
  "code": "lp-1504444",
  "name": "name3"
}]
```

I would like to map those two list of object by code to have an output like :

```
const objectResult: [{
  "code": "lap-143240121",
  "index": 0,
  "name": "name1"
}, {
  "code": "lap-15040293",
  "index": 1,
  "name": "name2"
}, {
  "code": "lp-1504444",
  "index": 2,
  "name": "name3"
}]
```

Comment: Please tell what you have tried.

Comment: Pretty easy answer there, but I agree with @angelo, you gotta at least make an effort to solve this.

Comment: thanks gentleman. It's because I didn't succeed it that I posted. I didn't know how to add a value from one to another. Here is my code                                                    
    for (var val of obj1){
            var v = obj2.filter(item=>item.code === val.code)
            let trial = obj2.filter(function (obj) { 
                
                return obj.code === val.code; 

            }).map(function (os) { 
                return os.code; 
            })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` to iterate `object2` and then use rest operator to return an `object` which consist of all the elements and the name from `object1`

```js
const object1 = [{
  "code": "lap-143240121",
  "index": 0
}, {
  "code": "lap-15040293",
  "index": 1
}, {
  "code": "lp-1504444",
  "index": 2
}, {
  "code": "lp-150440987",
  "index": 3
}]

const object2 = [{
  "code": "lap-143240121",
  "name": "name1"
}, {
  "code": "lap-15040293",
  "name": "name2"
}, {
  "code": "lp-1504444",
  "name": "name3"
}];


const obj3 = object2.map((item) => {
  return {
    ...item, // will consist all the items from object2
    // get index from object1 where the code matches
    index: object1.find(elem => elem.code === item.code).index 
  }
});

console.log(obj3)
```

Answer (score 1):

- transform the object1 to `Map` with value of `code` as key and whole `object` as value
- iterate on object2 search `code` from object2 in the above created map, if found merge the properties